# cannot create foreign key MySQLworkbench

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

i need help with creating a foreign key between two tables for some reason i'm repeatedly being told that Customer Number doesn't exist when it does

here is the code for the first table

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Customer;
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    CustomerNumber int NOT NULL,
    CustomerName varchar(255),
    CustomerAddress varchar(255),
    CustomerPhoneNumber varchar(255),
    JoinDate varchar(255),
    PetName varchar(255),
    PayScheme varchar(255),
    PremiumPayDate varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNumber)
    );
```

here is the code for the second

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Policies;    
CREATE TABLE Policies
(
    PolicyID int NOT NULL,
    PolicyNumber int NOT NULL,
    PetType varchar(255),
    EffectiveDate varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (PolicyID),
        CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerNumber
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNumber) 
REFERENCES Customer(CustomerNumber)
);
```

i am repeatedly being told that the key column Customer number doesn't exist

Comment: It's right. Where is customerNumber column in the policies table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Policies` table is missing the `customerNumber` column. You need to add it before declaring a `foreign key` constraint on it. Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Policies;    
CREATE TABLE Policies
(
    PolicyID int NOT NULL,
    PolicyNumber int NOT NULL,
    PetType varchar(255),
    CustomerNumber int NOT NULL,  --Added here
    EffectiveDate varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (PolicyID),
        CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerNumber
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNumber) 
REFERENCES Customer(CustomerNumber)
);
```

Comment: ahhh i thought it just retrieved it thanks man this was a life saver